# Copying android .apk to another .apk file through java code and over-ride its assets files?

Tags: android, apk, assets, android-assets

is it possible to create .apk file by copying an already existing .apk file and modifying its assets folder? I have some information in a file in assets folder containing server ip and port to which the user is to connect. Users are from different regions and have to connect through different servers. can anyone tell me how to implement this?

Comment: have multiple asset files and based on user's region, use the appropriate server ip & port. Don't go on modifying apk for every other region.

Comment: Or cant you just store some properties file with known name into a known external location and read from that?

Comment: Actually it is a library application for library users. users has to connect to the specific library server. How would i get to know which library server he has to connect on application level? That is, how would i get to know which property file to read for server ip and port?

Comment: This is the complete scenario:
I have a common server with database that contains a unique primary key plus user information who can use the android application(usename,password etc etc). All I want is to get that primary key when a user launches the application first time so that i can get the username password and other info from databse.

Comment: The first time the app runs, you should have the app connect to a "dispatcher server" and authenticate. The "dispatcher server" can then look into the common database, check the authentication and return a URL that points to the correct server for the user's region. The app can store that URL in shared preferences and always connect to the specific regional server.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a comment with my recommended solution to this problem. However, here's an answer to your question:

Of course you can unpack the APK, swap out the assets and then create a new APK from that. However, you will need to sign the APK again with the correct key.

If you are building the apps yourself, you can just build multiple APKs, each containing a different asset file. However, you would have to distribute these APKs by hand (ie: they can't be uploaded to Google Play) because they would each have the same package name and you cannot have multiple apps in the app store with the same package name.